# Are there any pandemics (like covid-19) in scriptures other than the one by Visuchi

Tags: scripture, yoga-vashishtha, disease

Yoga Vasistha contains the [story of Visuchika](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118127.html) and the [details of pandemic](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118128.html) caused by her.

Visuchika killed many humans for several years by entering through nostrils of human in form of very small needle. And all other details given are similar to that of a pandemic.

Does scriptures mention any other pandemics other than the one caused by Visuchi?

Comment: Looks like Covid is a kid compared to Visuchi. If Visuchi reappears we would be needing metal masks. :P

Comment: hahaha @Rickross